# Powershell: High Performing conversion of Name and Value Array into Parseable format - How can I make this Faster

Tags: json, powershell, parsing, optimization, pscustomobject

**How can I make my code a lot more performant when I wish to make an easily/fast parseable object/PSCustomObject from a JSON payload `$JSON`?**

An example of the structure of the PAYLOAD I receive is:

```
[
    {
        "name":  "system.enablenetflow",
        "value":  "false"
    },
    {
        "name":  "system.deviceGroupId",
        "value":  "186,3060"
    },
    {
        "name":  "system.prefcollectorid",
        "value":  "144"
    },
    {
        "name":  "system.collectorplatform",
        "value":  "windows"
    }
]
```

As you can see its in a very annoying format.

Note that the payloads I attempt to parse are much larger and variable in count from 500 of these Name/Value objects to 50000, rather than just the 4 listed above.

###########################################################################

**MY GOAL**

To have this turn into a key:value pair scenario for easier parsing later

*NOT This*:

With the JSON I have to do `$JSON.where({$_.name -eq "system.enablenetflow"}).value`

*YES THIS*:

I want the end state to be that the new variable `$obj` I create will let me get the value with `$obj."system.enablenetflow"`

###########################################################################

**MY CURRENT ATTEMPT THAT IS SUPER SLOW**

I did the following:

1. Create an Empty PSCustomObject and saved it as variable `$obj`
2. Did a foreach method on the `$JSON` variable which iterated through the JSON Array
3. Add-Member to `$obj` with setting the 'name' as PropertyName and 'value' as PropertyValue

Heres a sample of my code:

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject] @{}
$json.foreach({
   $thisitem = $_
   $obj | Add-member -NotePropertyName $($thisitem.name) -NotePropertyValue $($thisitem.name)
})
```

**HOW CAN I MAKE THIS FASTER?**

Comment: Have you looked at the [ConvertFrom-JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Sample input JSON.
$json =  @'
[
    {
        "name":  "system.enablenetflow",
        "value":  "false"
    },
    {
        "name":  "system.deviceGroupId",
        "value":  "186,3060"
    },
    {
        "name":  "system.prefcollectorid",
        "value":  "144"
    },
    {
        "name":  "system.collectorplatform",
        "value":  "windows"
    }
]
'@

# Initialize the (ordered) result hashtable.
$result = [ordered] @{}

# Note: In PowerShell (Core) 7+, add -AsHashTable to the ConvertFrom-Json
#       call for additional performance gain, combined with -AsArray,
#       in which case you don't need the `(...)` around the call anymore.
foreach ($element in (ConvertFrom-Json $json)) {
  $result[$element.name] = $element.value
}
```

The above creates an *(ordered) hashtable* instead of a `[pscustomobject]` instance - especially if the latter are *iteratively* constructed via `Add-Member` calls.

Hashtables are lighter-weight and faster to construct than `[pscustomobject]` instances.

Using a `foreach` loop rather than processing the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) output in a *pipeline* via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) also speeds up processing.

PowerShell allows you to use the familiar dot notation also with hashtables; so, for instance, after running the above, you'll get:

```
PS> $result.'system.collectorplatform'
windows
```

If you do need `$result` to be a `[pscustomobject]` instance, you can simply cast the fully populated hashtable to that type:

```
PS> $obj = [pscustomobject] $result; $obj.'system.collectorplatform'
windows
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Using [ORDERED] and converting the result with just adding [pscustomobject] to the front of the ordered hashtable were the critical pieces that I was missing.... I needed PSCUSTOMOBJECTs because I wanted to be able to easily do out-gridview and write to CSV and Excel etc

Comment: Good to know, @AdilZ; glad to hear it was helpful.